# Jmeter- how to achieve throughput same as the user count in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

How can I acheive below transaction per hour. I tried to control login by using once only controller ,But transaction per hour is still more than 70. How to handle this?

Overall User count is 70

Transaction per hour for login -- 70
Transaction per hour for homepage -- 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need JMeter to execute exact amount of transactions, not more, not less - go for [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)

[image]

Similarly you can configure 100 homepage transactions.

In order to evenly distribute 70/100 transactions for the duration of one hour time frame you can play with ramp-up period and [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)

Be aware that you won't be able to achieve different throughputs for different samplers under the same Thread Group as JMeter will always wait for the previous sampler to finish prior to executing the next one hence it will act at the speed of the slowest sampler.

More information: [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other options:

1. Use the **Arrivals Thread Group**. This TG will allow you to
   configure the desire average throughput (ATP); the TG will
   instantiate the required threads needed to achieve the ATP goal (no
   guessing)
2. Use the **Concurrency Thread Group** together with **Throughput
   Shaping Timer**. These option will also autoscale the number of Vusers
   [see more information here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin)

Be aware that the downside of these options is that vusers is are instantiate using a fixed **pacing**. In general, this is not how rusers interface with an application in the real world.